# SQL - Show 0 if no results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with result set below:

```
C_Date    C_Time     Day        L_TID     Terminal_Name      Branch   Branch_Name           L_UID     C_Name            C_Unique    L_Result    C_Card
20140327  905        Thursday   4640601   046406 Virdi 4000  46406    Sr Blue Downs 046406  1220578   Tsutsu;Simamkele  1220578     0
```

What is happening is that if a branch has no information, it does not come up at all. What I would like is for it to show 0s if possible.
I've tried doing a CASE on the C_Date column however everything is just coming up as Unknown and still not bringing my branch up!

Below is my script:

```
    SELECT 

 tEnter.C_Date, tEnter.C_Time, 
 datename (dw,tEnter.C_Date) AS [Day], 
CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -7, 112) as [startdate],
CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -1, 112) as [enddate], 
            tEnter.L_TID, 
            tTerminal.C_Name AS Terminal_Name, 
            tTerminal.C_Office AS Branch, 
            tTerminal.C_Place AS Branch_Name, 
            tEnter.L_UID, 
        tEnter.C_Name, 
        tEnter.C_Unique,
        tEnter.L_Result, 
        tEnter.C_Card,
   CASE tEnter.C_Date
        WHEN 1 THEN '1' WHEN 0 THEN 'Nothing' ELSE 'Unknown' END AS 'Test'

INTO #TEMPTABLE

FROM         tEnter INNER JOIN
                      tTerminal ON tEnter.L_TID = tTerminal.L_ID

WHERE 

         tEnter.C_Date between CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -7, 112) and 
         CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -1, 112)

select * from #TEMPTABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, this did the trick.

```
        SELECT DISTINCT C_Office
        INTO #Branch
        FROM tTerminal

        SELECT 

        ISNULL(tEnter.C_Date,0) AS C_Date,
        ISNULL( tEnter.C_Time,0) AS C_Time, 
        datename (dw,tEnter.C_Date) AS [Day], 
        CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -7, 112) as [startdate],
        CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -1, 112) as [enddate], 
                    tEnter.L_TID, 
                    tTerminal.C_Name AS Terminal_Name, 
                    BRN.C_Office AS Branch, 
                    tTerminal.C_Place AS Branch_Name, 
                    tEnter.L_UID, 
                tEnter.C_Name, 
                tEnter.C_Unique,
                tEnter.L_Result, 
                tEnter.C_Card

        INTO #TEMPTABLE2 
        FROM #Branch as BRN

                LEFT OUTER JOIN tEnter 
                on tEnter.C_Office = BRN.C_Office
                AND (tEnter.C_Date between CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -7, 112) and CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -1, 112))

                LEFT OUTER JOIN tTerminal 
                ON tEnter.L_TID = tTerminal.L_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a `Right Outer Join`. I also think that you might need to move this `Where` clause into the `Join` condition. The `tEnter` fields may be null because of the outer join, but when you add them to the where condition, you unintentional drop all the rows with no date (your rows with nulls).

```
  INTO #TEMPTABLE
  FROM         tEnter RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  tTerminal ON tEnter.L_TID = tTerminal.L_ID
  AND
     tEnter.C_Date between CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -7, 112) and 
     CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE () -1, 112)ckquote
```

Comment: No joy, branch still doesn't show. Will carry on trying